How to use verbatim code in the bib file?
I have tried using \mintinline but it adds braces which should not be there when used in the bib file.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{minted}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}
    map~\autocite{mymap}
    \mintinline[breaklines,breakafter=)|]{bash}{iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 data | sed -En 's/([0-9]+ +){4}([0-9.]+) +([0-9.]+) +(([^ ]|.[^ ])+).*/\2,\3(\4); /p' | tr -d '\n'}

    \printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}

main.bib:
@online{mymap,
    url = {http://share.mapbbcode.org/},
    urldate = {2024-07-18},
    note = {[map] BBCode (\url{https://mapbbcode.org/}) generated with \mintinline[breaklines,breakafter=)|]{bash}{iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 data | sed -En 's/([0-9]+ +){4}([0-9.]+) +([0-9.]+) +(([^ ]|.[^ ])+).*/\2,\3(\4); /p' | tr -d '\n'}},
}


Note the {} which have been added after \2 in the references, this does not happen when using the same command directly in the tex file.

I would do it this way:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{minted}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

where main.bib
@preamble{
{\newcommand\mymapNote{[map] BBCode (\url{https://mapbbcode.org/}) generated with \mintinline[breaklines,breakafter=)|]{bash}{iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 data | sed -En 's/([0-9]+ +){4}([0-9.]+) +([0-9.]+) +(([^ ]|.[^ ])+).*/\2,\3(\4); /p' | tr -d '\n'}}}
}

@online{mymap,
url = {http://share.mapbbcode.org/},
urldate = {2024-07-18},
note = {\mymapNote},
}



nice, how did you find the @preamble trick? I have not seen it in the biblatex documentation. I would have expected it in section 2.1, the Entry Types in the Database Guide.

This is a BibTeX trick, but can also be used in BibLaTeX. http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf

It works to move the code in to a separate file and then input that file in \printbibliography:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{breakaftersymbolpre=}

\let\codeinbib=\relax
\newcommand\defcodeinbib{%
    \def\codeinbib##1{%
        \begingroup
            \let\par=\relax
            \input{code/##1}%
        \endgroup
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    map~\autocite{mymap}

    \begingroup
    \defcodeinbib
    \printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
    \endgroup
\end{document}

code/mymap.tex:
\mintinline[breaklines, breakafter=)|]{bash}{iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 data | sed 's/[()]//g' | sed -En 's/([0-9]+ +){4}([0-9.]+) +([0-9.]+) +(([^ ]|.[^ ])+).*/\2,\3(\4); /p' | tr -d '\n'}

main.bib:
@online{mymap,
    url = {http://share.mapbbcode.org/},
    urldate = {2024-07-18},
    note = {[map] BBCode (\url{https://mapbbcode.org/}) generated with \codeinbib{mymap}},
}

With this approach minted is not required, a simple \verb would work instead of a \mintinline but that would not allow line breaks.
